# Згідно з чим "згідно чому" є неправильним узгодженням іменника з прийменником?

Tags: росіянізм, словосполучення, відмінювання, іменники, прийменники

Досить часто (навіть тут на [SE](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE)) вживають словосполучення **прийменник *"згідно"* + іменник у давальному відмінку**.

Утім, добре пам'ятаю ще з університетських часів, як професор Ющук І.П. наголошував, що таке узгодження - це калька з російської, від **согласно чему**, а правильні українські відповідники: **згідно з чим** або **відповідно до чого**.

СУМ каже нам таке:

> [Згідно](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=35263&page=1119)
>
> 2. у знач. прийм., **з оруд. в. та прийм. з.** Уживається на означення відповідності до чого-небудь. *Моя господиня віддала мені.. сю хату за
>      15 р., хоч я сама бачу, що **згідно з** тутешніми звичаями вона варта
>      20 р.* (Леся Українка, V, 1956, 207); — *Спав **згідно з** уставом —
>      сім годин* (Дмитро Ткач, Моряки, 1948, 12).
>
> [Відповідно](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=13417&page=437)
>
> 2. у знач. прийм., **з род. (у сполуч. з прийм. до) і (заст.) дав. в**. Уживається на позначення узгодженості між чимось, залежності від
>      чогось. *Він намагався у всьому товаристві завести козацькі порядки та звичаї **відповідно до** Гоголевої повісті* (С. Васильченко); *Чечель розглянув ворожі позиції і негайно заряджує всілякі зміни, **відповідно до** того, як через ніч змінив свої плани ворог* (Б. Лепкий);

А ось пояснення на ресурсі [СЛОВОПЕДІЯ. Уроки державної мови (з газети «Хрещатик»)](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53399/25787.html):

> Як слід сказати: **згідно рішення** чи **згідно з рішенням**?
>
> Щоб передавати поняття відповідності синтаксичними засобами, сучасна
>   українська мова має дві нормативні прийменниково-відмінкові форми:
>   **згідно з плюс орудний відмінок іменників**, **відповідно до плюс родовий відмінок іменників**. “*Спав згідно зі статутом – сім годин*”
>   (Дмитро Ткач), “*Відповідно до завдань оновлювалися й кадри*” (з
>   газети).
>
> Форми іменників із прийменниками **згідно з** та **відповідно до**
>   характерні для офіційно-ділового, наукового стилів.
>
> Буває, що **згідно** помилково сполучають з давальним або родовим
>   відмінком: *згідно повір’ю*, *згідно планів*, *згідно рішення*,
>   *згідно протокол*у. Ці утворення – наслідок впливу граматичної системи російської мови: *согласно поверью*, *согласно планам*. Треба:
>   **згідно з рішенням**, **згідно з протоколом**.
>
> Неправильні конструкції типу *відповідно з планами* і *згідно до
>   планів*. Не відповідає сучасній літературній нормі також форма
>   іменників з прийменником *у відповідності з* (калька з російської мови
>   *в соответствии с*).

А чи є якесь загальне правило, яке регулює відмінкові узгодження іменників у прийменникових словосполученнях?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

*Мовні ресурси*

- [Лабораторія компʼютерної лінгвістики Інституту філології Київського національного університету імені Тараса Шевченка](http://www.mova.info/article.aspx?l1=114&DID=340)
- [Мова – ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/zgidno-z-i-vidpovidno-do) (зображення вище)
- [Online Corrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B7%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7/)

Розділяють ті самі думки, що й [Борис Рогоза](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), професор [Іван Ющук](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D1%89%D1%83%D0%BA_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9F%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87).

*Корпуси* лише підтверджують ті думки

- Браунський

  - *[згідно](https://github.com/brown-uk/corpus/search?q=%22%D0%B7%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%22)*
  - *[відповідно](https://github.com/brown-uk/corpus/search?q=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%22)*
- [Інституту філології Київського національного університету імені Тараса Шевченка](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx?l1=209)
- Лейпцизького університету

  - *[з (1,268,580), із (156,127), зі (71,072)](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?word=%D0%B7%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE&corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014), чинного (34,767) …*
  - *[до (2,614,670)](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE), абзацами (6,920) …*
- [Паралельний польсько-український](http://nl.ijs.si/ME/V4/msd/html/msd.S-uk.html) *(згідно)*
- Паралельний московицько-український Інституту московицької мови

  - *[згідно](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mysent=&mysize=9383923&mysentsize=919437&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=para&sort=gr_tagging&env=alpha&mycorp=%28lang%3A%22ukr%22%20%7C%20lang_trans%3A%22ukr%22%29&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F1%EE%E3%EB%E0%F1%ED%EE&gramm1=&flags1=&sem1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&flags2=&sem2=) — согласно*
  - *[відповідно](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mysent=&mysize=9383923&mysentsize=919437&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=para&sort=gr_tagging&env=alpha&mycorp=%28lang%3A%22ukr%22%20%7C%20lang_trans%3A%22ukr%22%29&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F1%EE%EE%F2%E2%E5%F2%F1%F2%E2%E8%E5&gramm1=&flags1=&sem1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%F1&gramm2=&flags2=&sem2=) — соотвествие + с*

Доволі [показово](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2576/), що деякі наші *сучасні* автори вживають цю конструкцію саме як *согласно чему*, коли більш природньо для нашої мови є *за чим*, наприклад *за даними науковцями*.

---

[Щодо загального правила, яке регулює відмінкові узгодження іменників у прийменникових словосполученнях.](http://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/sintaksis_i_punktuacija/prijmennikovi_sintaksichni_slovoformi_imennikiv/7-1-0-161) Приведу лише ті, що мають відношення до наших прийменникових зворотів.

3. Словоформи з прийменником **з** творяться з родовим, знахід­ним і орудним відмінками іменників. Кожна з цих словоформ має свої відмінні значення.

У поєднанні з **родовим відмінком** іменника прийменник **з** вказує на:

- рух зсередини, з якогось середовища, з поверхні: *зі школи, з поля, з хмари, з роботи*;
- причину, підставу дії: *з жарту, з нудьги, з холоду, з дозволу*;
- матеріал, знаряддя: *з дерева, з чашки, з лука*;
- ознаку за галуззю: *(підручник) з географії, (фахівець) з медицини*;
- обʼєкт негативного ставлення: *(глузувати, насміхатися, знущатися, кепкувати, глумитися) з когось*.

У поєднанні із **знахідним відмінком** іменника прийменник **з** означає приблизність, порівняння: *з десяток, з годину, з діжку, з кулак*.

**У поєднанні з орудним відмінком іменника прийменник з вказує на взаємозвʼязки предметів, супровідні обставини:** *з братом, з людьми, з шумом, з плугами, з проханням.*

6. Словоформи з прийменником **до** творяться **тільки з родовим відмінком** іменників.

Вони в основному позначають:

- мету руху, його просторову або часову межу: *до школи, до берега, до Києва, до серця, до ранку;*
- **предмет, до якого виявляється певне ставлення:** *(добрий) до всіх, (охочий) до танців, (швидкий) до роботи, (готовність) до дії, (звернутися) до знайомого*;
- **міру, кількість:** *до краплі, до решти, до знемоги, до дна.*