# Чи закінчували інститути ті, хто пише "вул. Інституцька"?

Tags: орфографія, приголосні, чергування

Зустріла такий неоковирний варіант написання назви вулиці **Інститутської** - **`Інституцька`**:

- на ресурсі [Bankchart. Рейтинги банківських послуг](http://www.bankchart.com.ua/spravochniki/otdeleniya/id/35900):

> Відділення Ощадбанку у м. Київ Місце розташування на карті та телефони
>   відділення Ощадбанку у м. Київ за адресою: вул. **`Інституцька`**, 2

- на [офіційному інтернет-порталі КМДА](http://kievcity.gov.ua/news/52224.html):

> 7 липня орієнтовно з 18:00 до 23:00 у зв’язку з проведенням маршу до
>   дня народження Мирослава Мисли (відповідно до звернення ВО «Свобода») 
>   виконуватиметься призупинення або часткове обмеження руху транспорту
>   вулицями, якими пролягає маршрут заходу, а саме: від Арсенальної площі
>   – вул. Грушевського – Кріпосним провулком – вул. **`Інституцькою`** –
>   вул. Хрещатик (від Майдану Незалежності до Європейської площі) –
>   Володимирським узвозом – вул. Сагайдачного – до Контрактової площі.

Професор Ющук І.П. у посібнику [Практикум з правопису і граматики української мови](https://ushchuk.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/d196.pdf), **§ 12. Зміни приголосних при додаванні суфіксів -ськ(ий), -ств(о) (Фонетика і правопис. Зміни приголосних)** зазначає:

> 3. Якщо твірна основа закінчується на зубний **`д`** або **`т`**, то у вимові відбуваються різні зміни, а саме:
>
> а) **на стику твірної основи і суфікса чується [дз], [ц]**: люд + ський
>   [лˊудзˊкий], люд + ство [лˊудзтво], брат + ський [брацˊкий], брат +
>   ство [брацтво];
>
> б) **кінцеві звуки твірної основи [т] і [ст] при збігу приголосних не
>   вимовляються**: студент + ський [студенˊсˊкий], студент + ство
>   [студенство], турист + ський [турисˊкий], модерніст + ський
>   [модернˊісˊкий].
>
> **Але на письмі ці зміни не позначаються — такі слова пишемо за морфологічним принципом** (див. § 2, п. 2): людський, людство,
>   братський, братство; студентський, студентство, туристський. **Виняток
>   становлять  слова** **`міський`** [міст(о) + ський] і **`хвацький`**
>   [хват + ський], які пишуться за фонетичним принципом.

**Тож чи я пропустила поповнення винятків до зазначеного вище правила зміни приголосних (якщо так, то чи відображено це в якомусь правописі або деінде), чи це безграмотність авторів такого покручу?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ну, не звертаючи поки уваги на те, як правильно згідно з сучасними нормами, зазначу, що слово «інститутський» люди майже протягом усього його існування періодично намагалися писали за фонетичним принципом. Ось як фраза із [повісті Івана Нечуй-Левицького «Хмари» (1871)](//uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8_(%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B9-%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) —

> Той світ вона постерігала вже **по-інститутському**: той світ здавався їй великим балом, з музиками, з танцями, з кавалерами в золотих еполетах, з послами турецькими й британськими, котрі здавались їй молодесенькими, надзвичайної краси паничиками, з русявими кучерями, як у янголів.

— була надрукована у [виданні 1874 року](//books.google.com/books?id=-ylfAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA125&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%22):

> Той світ вона постерегала вже **по-институцький**: той світ здавався їй великим балом, з музиками, з танцями, з кавалерами в золотих еполетах, з послами турецькими й британськими, котрі здавались їй молодесенькими, незвичайної краси паничами, з русявими кучерями, як у янголів.

<sub>(в [переліку помилок (ераті)](//books.google.com/books?id=-ylfAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA377) це не зазначено як помилку)</sub>.

Ба, навіть саме прізвище Нечуй-**Левицький** (в оригіналі — просто Левицький; припускаю — від «[левіт](http://sum.in.ua/s/levit)»/«[левит](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82&scope=ukr&dicts=1)») зафіксувало «неправильне» написання — на відміну від, наприклад, прізвища [Левитський](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9), що його носять інші видатні люди. Дехто навіть у XXI столітті пише «[факультецький](//books.google.com/books?id=fb8XAQAAIAAJ&q=%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)» (хоч мені особисто це смішно, я вводив це в пошук просто як жартівливу спробу довести до абсурду).

Але відповідно до сучасних норм — правильно лише «**інститутський**» ([1](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9), [2](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=39288&page=1234)).

Comment: Гарна відповідь, дякую! Лише зауважу, що *згідно до* [вважають](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1508/%D0%97%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7-%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%94-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC) неправильним варіантом. Ліпше *згідно з* або *відповідно до*. Чи ви іншої думки?

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, дякую! Я пам'ятав, що не дуже добре «згідно наказу» і треба якийсь прийменник. Але прийменник сплутав :).

Comment: Ще один приклад — народна казка про [пана Коцького](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Answer (score 3):

Коли натрапив на таке (про що піде мова), то згадав це питання і рішив подїлитися, тут буде не лише **тс** — **ц**, а й инші цїкавинки.

Як правильно [Sasha](/users/4/sasha) вже розповів, товік і позатовік мали напрям до звукового запису супроти словопохідного.

Ось що можна натрапити в книзі:
[Українська граматика](http://shron3.chtyvo.org.ua/Tymchenko_Yevhen/Ukrainska_hramatyka.pdf#page=28) / Проф. [Євген Тимченко](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%84%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). – 2-е видання. – Товариство "Час" у Києві. – Київ: Дpукарня Університету св. Володимиpа Акц. Т-ва дpук. і видавн. діла H. Т. Коpчак-Hовицького, Меринговська вул., д. 6. 1917. – 168 c.

<sub>*28*</sub>

> **чсь**, **чьсь** **тьсь** дає звук **ц**, **ць**, напр. *ткацтво*, *багацтво*, *козацький*, *галицький*, *свіцький*, *діцький*, *багацько*.

Нагадаю, що зараз пишемо наприклад [*світський*](http://sum.in.ua/s/svitsjkyj), [*багатство*](http://sum.in.ua/s/baghatstvo)… Далї просто для доповнення:

> **дc**, **дьсь** — **дз**, **дзь**: *сусідзтво*, *сусідзький*, *людзький*, *громадзький*
>
> **жьсь** — **зь**: *паризький*, *запорозький*, *празький*, *петербузький*. *Різдво* з *рож(дь)ство*.