# Тайна чи таємна вечеря?

Tags: вибір-слова, прикметники

Чи можна вживати 2 слова: **"тайна", "таємна"**, на позначення картини Леонардо да Вінчі "Тайна/таємна вечеря"? На просторах інтернету знаходжу двояке вживання: ["Таємна вечеря"](https://www.ar25.org/article/postati-v-obrazi-tayemna-vecherya.html),["Тайна вечеря"](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F_(%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%87%D1%96)).
В СУМі біля слова ["тайний"](http://sum.in.ua/s/tajnyj) знаходимо позначку *рідко*, біля слова ["таємний"](http://sum.in.ua/s/tajemnyj) не знаходимо ніяких особливостей слововживання.

Отож, цікавить як правильно картина Леонардо да Вінчі "Тайна/ Таємна вечеря"?

Answer (score 2):

На мою думку, правильна назва картини (фрески) "Тайна вечеря" оскільки на ній зображено  Ісуса Христа з апостолами та скорботне з ними застілля у вечір перед самим розп'яттям.

Так і слова "тайна" та "таємна" варто шукати в церковних словниках.

Слова "тайна" присутнє в [словнику церковно-обрядової термінології](http://slovopedia.org.ua/96/53410/1031440.html)

> тайна свята, тайна церковна Те саме, що таїнство

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F) містить статтю з назвою "Тайна вечеря"

Леонардо да Вінчі італійський митець, назва фрески  "Ultima cena", що в перекладі - [Остання вечеря](https://www.dict.com/%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B8/Ultima%20cena)

Answer (score 0):

Згідно до СУМу краще вживати слово "таємний", бо, крім позначки "рідко", біля слова "тайний стоїть ще позначка "розмовне". Тому варіант "Таємна вечеря" цілком є прийнятний.

Але коли ми говоримо "Тайна вечеря", то, гадаю, це також не буде помилкою. Вікіпедія пише:

> «Тайна вечеря» або **рідше: «Таємна вечеря»** ...

І якщо заглянути в словник Глосб і ввести російське "Тайная вечеря", то побачимо, що найчастіший варіант перекладу буде "тайна вечеря". Також там є такі варіанти як "остання вечеря", "Господня вечеря", "таємна вечеря".

Хоч словник [Савченко](http://univer.nuczu.edu.ua/tmp_metod/1047/%D1%E0%E2%F7%E5%ED%EA%EE%20%CB.%20%C3._%D0%EE%F1%B3%E9%F1%FC%EA%EE-%F3%EA%F0%E0%BF%ED%F1%FC%EA%E8%E9%20%F1%EB%EE%E2%ED%E8%EA%20%F1%EB%EE%E2%EE%F1%EF%EE%EB%F3%F7%E5%ED%FC.%20%D2%F0%F3%E4%ED%EE%F9%B3%20%EF%E5%F0%E5%EA%EB%E0%E4%F3.pdf) дає лише варіант "таємна вечеря" і так само інший [Російсько-український словник сталих словосполучень](http://ros-ukr-idioms.wikidot.com/t).

Гадаю, що коли ми говоримо про картину чи подію із Біблії, то допустимі два варіанта, однак в інших випадках варто надавати перевагу слову "таємний", а не "тайний".

Comment: [Згідно з..., відповідно до... ](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1508/%D0%97%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7-%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%94-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC)